# How to check if an m.2 NVMe disk has died without the use of manufacturers tools?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, bios

My server died a few days ago and since I was having some problems with the motherboard. I assumed it had died and bought a new one. Once changed, I noticed that neither the BIOS nor a live Ubuntu USB would detect my NVMe SSD.

I decided to install that SSD in my main PC which has two m.2 interfaces, and it will not boot. Actually, it doesn't even make it to the BIOS. It just freezes on the American Megatrends screen.

Could this be a dead SSD? Is there any way to be 100% sure? It is a cheap Chinese made SSD from a brand called Kingdian.

Comment: I reliably test m.2 and regular SSD drives with the hardware diagnostics tool supplied by the computer manufacturer. Best way.  Find the maker of the SSD drive and get the drive diagnostics.  Samsung uses Samsung Magician and I have and use that . All my SSD drives are Samsung. Manufacturer diagnostics usually have a bootable USB Key version which you will need here.

Comment: My problem here is that the ssd is a cheap one from a chinese brand called Kingdian. I doubt I'll be able to get a diagnostics tool.

Comment: @dvilela - If it's not detected in the BIOS nor an operating system, having a diagnostic tool, won't do much good anyways.

Comment: Get better SSD drives. Samsung are good. My ThinkPad m.2 Samsung is good for 600 TBW and I am at 35 TBW after 4 years.

Comment: @John most well-known brands are good but all of them (even Samsung) can, and will, fail. I would hoewever stay away from the cheaper "fantasy" SSD brands found on Amazon or Ebay or other large online retailers. BTW I have (profesionally and personally) used many (well-known) brands of SSD and they are mostly at least as reliable as mechanical HDDs. They can still fail unexpectedly and in many different ways.

Comment: all of them (even Samsung) can, and will, fai  ..... True (mean time to fail) , but the 600 TBW rating is a good indication of quality.